# How to play as Anubis?

Tags: smite

I unlocked Anubis and after the first few games I found myself struggling to get to grips with the god.

His 1 (Plague of Locusts) and ult leave you open to attack.  Also, it feels that his only real method of escape is to pull off a skill shot with his 2 (Mummify).

In contrast, I see other Anubis players dominating their lanes (Conquest) and with positive kill/death ratios.

How should I play as Anubis?

Comment: It should be noted that a lot of your success with X god will also depend on your team. For instance, as the mid laner, your success using a mage will depend on your jungler and how you compliment with him or her. There's certainly a place for learning how to optimize rotations, but "I see other players dominating their lanes" could be the result of dozens of factors.

Comment: @Ellesedil - completely agree that there are many factors to this.  However, I observed that others were competent with Anubis whereas initially I just couldn't figure out how to use him effectively/correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I find that you cannot really play Anubis passively.  You need to go all in with a few ability combos.

---

I have found the following combos very effective:

**3 - 2 - 1**
Throw down the Grasping Hands, then immediately Mummify.  To begin with I was using Mummify first.  However, doing it after means that the Grasping Hands will do more damage.  The Mummify skill shot is also slightly easier because the opponent tends to freeze or delay to then change direction as you land the Grasping Hands.  Once stunned, the Plague of Locusts can be used to deal additional damage on the easy target.

I would say that because the Plague of Locusts leaves you vulnerable (as you are rooted and relatively close), you shouldn't attempt this during team fights.

**3 - 2 - ult**
Much like the strategy above, except you are using your ult.  With this method you are looking to kill off the opponent.  I wouldn't try this combo unless I was confident in getting the kill.

**3 - 2**
This simple combo allows you to knock a little health off the enemy god.  I use this if I don't want to risk using my 1 or ult.  It is also useful to work out if you are doing good damage to a particular god.

---

In terms of escaping, I use the following:

**Cancelling**
You can cancel your 1 and ult.  This is very useful if you are about to get ganked or you miss your 2 (Mummify).

**Mummify**
Unfortunately, you just got to get good at the skill shot.  It isn't too hard once you stop panicking when an enemy god gets close.  Additionally, try to keep Mummify ready for situations that may lead you to being ganked or ambushed.  For example, going for jungle buffs.

There may be situations where you can go 2 - 1 on an ambush.  Mummify to stop the threat then hit them with the Plague of Locusts.  However, this is only going to work if you think the damage you deal is enough to push the enemy back.